# Print rank from sum in PHP & MySQL in 1,1,3,4, etc Order

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below SQL query from Stack Overflow, and it's working perfectly. [This is the link to the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799949/print-rank-from-sum-in-php-mysql/20730726#20730726).

I want the below query to output the rank in the following order if there is any tie:

> 1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,9,10.... etc.

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT idno, name, rank,total_score
FROM (SELECT *,  IF(@marks=(@marks:=total_score), @auto, @auto:=@auto+1) AS    rank 
FROM (SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT idno, name, SUM(score) AS total_score 
FROM jbit, 
(SELECT @auto:=0, @marks:=0) as init 
 GROUP BY name) sub ORDER BY total_score DESC)t) as result
WHERE idno ='1'
```

Comment: The original answer claims this code already handles ties. What is the problem you are experiencing, exactly?

Comment: Uh-oh. Have you asked five questions on the same topic?

Comment: Readers answering this question may first wish to check the OP's ranking SQL questions: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29388723), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29391651), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29451275), [four](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29452337) and [five](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29486804), so that work is not accidentally duplicated.

Comment: Thank you @halfer, my problem now is this; if two users have the same SUM(score), and there ranking will be, first user 1 and second user 1, i want the score of the third user to be 3 instead of 2, this is order of which i want the query to represent the ranking. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can sort by values even with ties using the standard `ORDER BY`. It'll return result rows in order as you mentioned; `1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 10`.

```
SELECT idno, name, rank, total_score FROM table_name ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: thank your @DACrosby, but i am not really seeking for the query to sort by that order, but rather i want the query to return, the ranking of users in that order, lets assume USER1 ranks 2, and USER2 ranks 2, i want USER3 to be ranked 3rd instead of 2nd. thank you

Comment: Okay, so instead of `1, 1, 3, 4...` you'd like `1, 2, 3, 4...`. Try `GROUP BY rank ORDER BY rank` - the grouping should cut out duplicate ranks.

Comment: thank you @DACrosby, but it is giving me error, i want the rank position to be in this order 1,2,2,4,5,6,6,8 etc. thank you